# CSS counter in url

Tags: html, css

I am interested in setting the images next to list items dynamically based on it's position. You can see below that I am using the counter feature of CSS to keep track of the list items, and that I am trying to specify an image as the list style type using the counter.

```
ul{
    counter-reset:list;
}
li
{
    counter-increment:list;
    list-style:disc outside url("http://dummyimage.com/" counter(list) "x" counter(list) "");
}
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

What is the correct way of getting the counter to work in a url declaration? Is it even possible?

Comment: Would've been so cool if this actually worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

url cannot be compose out of multiple string

for example, this work:

```
url("http://dummyimage.com/10x10");
```

but this doesn't work :

```
url("http://dummyimage.com/" "10x10");
```

the counter has nothing to do with it

On the other hand, you could be able to do it using variables, try to take a look at LessCSS for axample.

Answer (score 3):

`counter()` function can only be used for `content` property. URL composition, like the one you are trying to create above, is impossible in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, what you are trying to achieve, but here's the sample code that you mind find useful: [sample code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akzxl)

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul { counter-reset: list; }
li {
  counter-increment: list;
  list-style: disc outside url("http://placekitten.com/20/20");
}
li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content:"Item " counter(list) ". ";
}
```